# On left and right inverses of functions

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let $F: A \to B$ and $ G: B \to A $. Then

$ G = F^{-1}$ iff $G \circ F = I_A$ and $F \circ G = I_B$.

My Solution:

Now to prove if two functions are equal we have to show that both their domains are equal and all the elements in their domains have the same values in their co-domains.

(a) Let us take $G = F^{-1}$. Now domain of $(G \circ F = I_A) =$ Domain of $F$ = A = Domain of $ I_A$. Same could be done with the other statement. Now let us take an element $x$ to be an element of A. Then there exists a $y$ such that $f(x) = y$. So $g[f(x)]=g(y)$ is equal to $x$ because $(x,y)$ belongs to $f$ then $(y,x)$ belongs to $f^{-1}$. So $g[f(x)]=g(y) = x = I_A$ Same could be done with the other statement.

(b) Now let us take $G \circ F = I_A$ and $F \circ G = I_B$. As $I_A$ is one-to-one $F$ is one-to-one. And as $I_B$ is onto $B$, $F$ is onto $B$. Now this is where I get stuck. I don't know how will I be able to show $ G = F^{-1}$.

Comment: What is your definition of $F^{-1}$?

Comment: The Inverse Function of F.

Comment: Then what is your definition of inverse function of $F$?

Comment: Well F maps elements in its domain to its co domain. And $F^{-1}$ maps elements in the co domain of F back to its domain.

Comment: You probably mean to say that it is a function $G:B\rightarrow A$ that satisfies $G(F(x))=x$ for $x\in A$. Am I right?

Comment: ^Yes. That is what I meant. :)

Comment: Now suppose $A=\{a\}$ and $B$ is a set having more than one element. Then for functions $F:A\rightarrow B$ and $G:B\rightarrow A$ you will always have $G(F(x))=x$ for $x\in\{a\}$. Is $G$ the inverse of $F$ in this case?

Comment: No But F is one-to-one and onto. (I've stated this in the solution.)

Comment: The thing is that $G$ normally is *defined* to be the inverse function of $F$ if $G\circ F=1_A$ *and* $F\circ G=1_B$. So it seems that you are trying to prove something that is by definition the case. That's the reason why it was asked in comments what your definition of $F^{-1}$ was.

Comment: Okay But is my solution correct then. And how will I prove this if I wanted to.

Comment: If you take the definition of inverse of $F$ in my former comment then there is nothing to prove. If you take another definition then your solving can only be checked if you explicitly state this (alternative) definition in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I put aside what your definition of inverse function is (see
the comments) and I presume in (a) it was shown that $F^{-1}\circ F=1_{A}$
and $F\circ F^{-1}=1_{B}$.

Now suppose that $G\circ F=1_{A}$ for some function $G:B\rightarrow A$.

Then $G=G\circ1_{B}=G\circ F\circ F^{-1}=1_{A}\circ F^{-1}=F^{-1}$.